# Uncaught Exception while consuming web service in Blackberry

Tags: web-services, rest, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Application is not responding while consuming restful service if internet is connected but browsing is not working, in blackberry jre 5.0. Please guide me if there is any method to set the responce time out?

I am using this code to consume service.

```java
static HttpConnection con = null;
static InputStream is = null;
static StringBuffer rawResponse;

public static String Call(String url) throws IOException {
    try {
        url = url + getConnectionString() + ";";
        if (CheckConn()) {
            con = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
            is = con.openInputStream();
            byte[] responseData = new byte[10000];
            int length = 0;
            rawResponse = new StringBuffer();
            while (-1 != (length = is.read(responseData))) {
                rawResponse.append(new String(responseData, 0, length));
            }
        } else {
            Status.show("Internet service is not avaiable.");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Status.show("Internet is not responding");
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Status.show(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return rawResponse.toString();
}

public static String getConnectionString() {
    String connectionString = "";
    if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
        connectionString = ";interface=wifi";
    }
    else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {
        connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
    } 
    else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {
        String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();
        if (carrierUid == null) {
            connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
        } else {
            connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID=" + carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
        }
    } 
    else if (CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE) {
        connectionString = ";None";
    }
    return connectionString;
}


public static String getCarrierBIBSUid() {
    net.rim.device.api.servicebook.ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
    int currentRecord;
    for (currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++) {
        if (records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp")) {
            if (records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf("bibs") >= 0) {
                return records[currentRecord].getUid();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes i did but facing same problem.

Comment: you can access the internet on your browser ? run the url with your browser

Comment: no i just check that internet is working on browser or not

Comment: are you making a network connection on the event thread? never do it.

Answer (score 0):

use it

```
 url = url + getConnectionString() + ";ConnectionTimeout=25000";
```

Here timeout is given in milliseconds. Once timeout will happen , it can be handle in catch block.

Comment: i am still facing the same problem

Comment: it can't handle in catch block after connectionTimeout's time application terminated and display a message "Uncaught Exception app terminated...  "